# Beautiful Soup: Descending links of links matching patterns

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I know this is very green, but I'm trying to descend links in a website and want the capability to descend links of links of links with the requirement that links in each stage follow some simple pattern matching. I've seen some tutorials on displaying links but not on pattern matching or descending links of links. Some help would be appreciated.

For instance in this case:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

resp = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.gpsbasecamp.com/national-parks")
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, from_encoding=resp.info().getparam('charset'))

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print link['href']
```

Out:

```
/contact-gpsbasecamp.php
/privacy-policy.php
/terms-of-service.php
/
                National-Parks/map
/National-Historic-Parks
/National-Historic-Sites
/National-Monuments
/Other-NPS-Facilities
national-parks/Acadia_National_Park
national-parks/Arches_National_Park
national-parks/Badlands_National_Park
national-parks/Big_Bend_National_Park
national-parks/Biscayne_National_Park
national-parks/Black_Canyon_Of_The_Gunnison_National_Park
national-parks/Bryce_Canyon_National_Park
national-parks/Canyonlands_National_Park
national-parks/Capitol_Reef_National_Park
national-parks/Carlsbad_Caverns_National_Park
national-parks/Channel_Islands_National_Park
national-parks/Congaree_National_Park
national-parks/Crater_Lake_National_Park
national-parks/Cuyahoga_Valley_National_Park
national-parks/Death_Valley_National_Park
national-parks/Denali_National_Park_and_Preserve
national-parks/Dry_Tortugas_National_Park
national-parks/Everglades_National_Park
national-parks/Gates_Of_The_Arctic_National_Park_and_Preserve
national-parks/Glacier_Bay_National_Park_and_Preserve
national-parks/Glacier_National_Park
national-parks/Grand_Canyon_National_Park
national-parks/Grand_Teton_National_Park
national-parks/Great_Basin_National_Park
national-parks/Great_Smoky_Mountains_National_Park
national-parks/Guadalupe_Mountains_National_Park
national-parks/Haleakala_National_Park
national-parks/Hawaii_Volcanoes_National_Park
national-parks/Hot_Springs_National_Park
national-parks/Isle_Royale_National_Park
national-parks/Joshua_Tree_National_Park
national-parks/Katmai_National_Park_and_Preserve
national-parks/Kenai_Fjords_National_Park
national-parks/Kings_Mountain_National_Military_Park
national-parks/Kobuk_Valley_National_Park
national-parks/Lake_Clark_National_Park_and_Preserve
national-parks/Lassen_Volcanic_National_Park
national-parks/Mammoth_Cave_National_Park
national-parks/Mesa_Verde_National_Park
national-parks/Mount_Rainier_National_Park
national-parks/National_Park_of_American_Samoa
national-parks/National_Parks_of_New_York_Harbor
national-parks/North_Cascades_National_Park
national-parks/Olympic_National_Park
national-parks/Petrified_Forest_National_Park
national-parks/Redwood_National_and_State_Parks
national-parks/Rocky_Mountain_National_Park
national-parks/Saguaro_National_Park
national-parks/Sequoia_and_Kings_Canyon_National_Parks
national-parks/Shenandoah_National_Park
national-parks/Theodore_Roosevelt_National_Park
national-parks/Virgin_Islands_National_Park
national-parks/Voyageurs_National_Park
national-parks/Wind_Cave_National_Park
national-parks/Wolf_Trap_National_Park_for_the_Performing_Arts
national-parks/Wrangell_-_St_Elias_National_Park_and_Preserve
national-parks/Yellowstone_National_Park
national-parks/Yosemite_National_Park
national-parks/Zion_National_Park
http://www.gpsbasecamp.com
http://www.gpsbasecamp.com
/upload-gps-file.php
/download-gps-file.php
/national-parks
/state-parks


/mp3/index.php
```

How do I then descend **all of the** links containing "national-parks" to obtain information from within **links** at the next level?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: By descend do you mean to to? I'm unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: By descend I mean: follow the link to another link and then recover information from the destination web page. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Method 1 :

```
for link in soup.select('a[href^="national-parks"]'):
        print(link['href'])
```

Method 2 :

```
import re
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r"^national-parks")):
    print(link['href'])
```

those two method will match href which start with 'national-parks'

out:

```
national-parks/Acadia_National_Park
national-parks/Arches_National_Park
national-parks/Badlands_National_Park
national-parks/Big_Bend_National_Park
national-parks/Biscayne_National_Park
national-parks/Black_Canyon_Of_The_Gunnison_National_Park
national-parks/Bryce_Canyon_National_Park
national-parks/Canyonlands_National_Park
national-parks/Capitol_Reef_National_Park
national-parks/Carlsbad_Caverns_National_Park
national-parks/Channel_Islands_National_Park
national-parks/Congaree_National_Park
national-parks/Crater_Lake_National_Park
national-parks/Cuyahoga_Valley_National_Park
national-parks/Death_Valley_National_Park
national-parks/Denali_National_Park_and_Preserve
national-parks/Dry_Tortugas_National_Park
national-parks/Everglades_National_Park
national-parks/Gates_Of_The_Arctic_National_Park_and_Preserve
national-parks/Glacier_Bay_National_Park_and_Preserve
national-parks/Glacier_National_Park
national-parks/Grand_Canyon_National_Park
national-parks/Grand_Teton_National_Park
national-parks/Great_Basin_National_Park
national-parks/Great_Smoky_Mountains_National_Park
national-parks/Guadalupe_Mountains_National_Park
national-parks/Haleakala_National_Park
national-parks/Hawaii_Volcanoes_National_Park
national-parks/Hot_Springs_National_Park
national-parks/Isle_Royale_National_Park
national-parks/Joshua_Tree_National_Park
national-parks/Katmai_National_Park_and_Preserve
national-parks/Kenai_Fjords_National_Park
national-parks/Kings_Mountain_National_Military_Park
national-parks/Kobuk_Valley_National_Park
national-parks/Lake_Clark_National_Park_and_Preserve
national-parks/Lassen_Volcanic_National_Park
national-parks/Mammoth_Cave_National_Park
national-parks/Mesa_Verde_National_Park
national-parks/Mount_Rainier_National_Park
national-parks/National_Park_of_American_Samoa
national-parks/National_Parks_of_New_York_Harbor
national-parks/North_Cascades_National_Park
national-parks/Olympic_National_Park
national-parks/Petrified_Forest_National_Park
national-parks/Redwood_National_and_State_Parks
national-parks/Rocky_Mountain_National_Park
national-parks/Saguaro_National_Park
national-parks/Sequoia_and_Kings_Canyon_National_Parks
national-parks/Shenandoah_National_Park
national-parks/Theodore_Roosevelt_National_Park
national-parks/Virgin_Islands_National_Park
national-parks/Voyageurs_National_Park
national-parks/Wind_Cave_National_Park
national-parks/Wolf_Trap_National_Park_for_the_Performing_Arts
national-parks/Wrangell_-_St_Elias_National_Park_and_Preserve
national-parks/Yellowstone_National_Park
national-parks/Yosemite_National_Park
national-parks/Zion_National_Park
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the functionality you are looking for: 
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

resp = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.gpsbasecamp.com/national-parks")
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, from_encoding=resp.info().getparam('charset'))

nat_parks_linkns = [link['href'] for link in soup.find_all((href=re.compile("national-parks"))]
```

Then you can go to each link as you please again. (I haven't gotten to actually test the above code)

Comment: Check out this excellent video that covers some of what you are doing! https://youtu.be/N0ph2a6Vd7M You can ignore the multiprocessing part, but the web crawl is basically what you are doing it sounds like.